# How to get 2 domain canonical redirect in web.config to work

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, umbraco

I have an Umbraco CMS that is hosting 2 web sites with different domains.  I need to perform canonical redirects for each using the iis rewrite from the web.config.

Example: mydomain1.com -> www.mydomain1.com and mydomain2.com -> www.mydomain2.com.

I'm trying to get this to work but it isn't working correctly.
No redirecting at all and sometimes it will redirect to the other domain.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectToWWW" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(\S+)\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Is there a better way to do this in a shared hosting environment?

Comment: You have `enabled="false"` so there is no way this rule will be triggered!

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you. That may be my stupidest copy and paste error ever!

Comment: Happened to most of us :)